# How would I insert an .svg image as a symbol into latex?

Tags: graphics

If I have a symbol which is an .svg image, how would I insert it into as a symbol and not an image? Could I make it into a glyph or a font? How would one do that?

Comment: Create a custom font, with font editing software, which is beyond the scope of this list, I believe. Having done that you need to use the font in your document. If you created a TTF/OTF font, you could use `\fontspec` to switch the font as part of a custom command.

Comment: `svg` package provides an `\includesvg` command (there really isn't much difference in tex between a symbol and an included image, why do you need the former?

Comment: See [the package David Carlisle mentioned](http://ctan.org/pkg/svg). Whether it is a symbol or an image, TeX will still think it is just a box ;).

Comment: Thank you,  my problem is I intend to use it inside pstricks and I am not sure if that would be compatible.  I want to replace an .eps image inside a minipage. Would this still work?

Comment: The svg will basically work the same way as the eps if you are including that now, what do you want to do that you can't do with that that you could do with a character?

Comment: What I am doing is making playing cards out of pstricks and in truth I'm modifying what Olaf Encke did in his poker package.  So regretfully after 6 months of tinkering, yes, this is the only way to get what I want.  I've tried everything else LOL.

Comment: But I do appreciate all your help.